# How to start a new thread from JNI

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface

I need to start a new thread from native part of android application. It must be declared and defined in JNI. Does someone know how can I do it? If someone will post the example I would be very happy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Easiest way is to use C++11 thread class. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142759/latest-c11-features-with-android-ndk?lq=1) on how to enable C++11 with Android NDK. Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021527/android-ndk-r9b-and-compiling-c11) if you are having problems getting thread class to work. Then you can use it like this:

```
#include <thread>         // std::thread
         
void foo() 
{
   // do stuff...
}
        
void bar(int x)
{
   // do stuff...
}
        
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
Java_org_testjni_android_Game_someFunction(JNIEnv * env, jobject  obj)
{
   std::thread first (foo);     // spawn new thread that calls foo()
   std::thread second (bar,0);  // spawn new thread that calls bar(0)
        
    //main, foo and bar now execute concurrently
        
    // synchronize threads:
   first.join();                // pauses until first finishes
   second.join();               // pauses until second finishes
        
}
```

If you can't use C++11, just use pthread (POSIX thread), which isn't much different, except it's like old C:

```
#include <pthread.h>
    
    //This function will be called from a thread
    
void *call_from_thread(void *) {
    //do stuff
    return NULL;
}
    
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
Java_org_testjni_android_Game_someFunction(JNIEnv * env, jobject  obj)
{
        pthread_t t;
    
        //Launch a thread
        pthread_create(&t, NULL, call_from_thread, NULL);
    
        //Join the thread with the main thread
        pthread_join(t, NULL);
 }
```

Here's some [more info](https://web.archive.org/web/20141009112758/http://www.brokenteapotstudios.com/android-game-development-blog/2011/07/posix-threads-on-android.html) on using POSIX threads with Android.

Also you will need to look up how to bind the JNIEnv pointer to the current thread if you want to use it in any thread but the one the JNI function is called from. From the JNI spec:

> Creating the VM
>
> The JNI_CreateJavaVM() function loads and initializes a Java VM and
> returns a pointer to the JNI interface pointer. The thread that called
> JNI_CreateJavaVM() is considered to be the main thread.
>
> Attaching to the VM
>
> The JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv) is valid only in the current
> thread. Should another thread need to access the Java VM, it must
> first call AttachCurrentThread() to attach itself to the VM and obtain
> a JNI interface pointer. Once attached to the VM, a native thread
> works just like an ordinary Java thread running inside a native
> method. The native thread remains attached to the VM until it calls
> DetachCurrentThread() to detach itself.
>
> The attached thread should have enough stack space to perform a
> reasonable amount of work. The allocation of stack space per thread is
> operating system-specific. For example, using pthreads, the stack size
> can be specified in the pthread_attr_t argument to pthread_create.
>
> Detaching from the VM
>
> A native thread attached to the VM must call DetachCurrentThread() to
> detach itself before exiting. A thread cannot detach itself if there
> are Java methods on the call stack.

Comment: Are C++11 threads recommended over Boost threads?  Or are they the same.

Comment: They're not the same, I believe Boost has more features. Boost threads you can interrupt like Java or .NET. Here's comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241993/is-it-smart-to-replace-boostthread-and-boostmutex-with-c11-equivalents